# LWC to APEX JSON deserialization

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components

I am trying to pass the record from LWC JS to apex and trying to update the value before inserting it in apex.
I have apex compile error "**Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void deserialize(Account,System.Type) from the type System.JSON**"

Sample code below:

JS:

```
import createAccount from '@salesforce/apex/MyClass.createAccount';
@track error

function(){
let account = {'sObject' : 'Account'};
account.Name == 'Account Name 1'
account.Industry == 'IT'

createAccount({accRec : account})
.then(result => {
alert('account is added');
})
.catch(error => {
this.error = error;
});
}
```

APEX Class:

```
public class MyClass {

@AuraEnabled
public static Account createAccount(Account accRec){
Account acc = (Account)JSON.deserialize(accRecord, Account.class);
acc.Industry == 'Software';
insert acc;
return null;
}

}
```

Can anyone resolve this?

Comment: If the method already takes an Account - `createAccount(Account accRec)` - why do you need to deserialize it? Deserialization is from string, not Account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the client side, you have constructed the Account SObject:

```
let account = {'sObject' : 'Account'};
account.Name == 'Account Name 1'
account.Industry == 'IT'
```

You do not need to deserialize it as you already have a Account SObject:

```
public static Account createAccount(Account accRec){
    // below deserialization is not required
    // Account acc = (Account)JSON.deserialize(accRecord, Account.class);
    accRec.Industry == 'Software';
    insert accRec;
```

Its always helpful to read and understand the error message carefully, it mostly gives us a clue on what is going wrong:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void deserialize(Account,System.Type) from the type System.JSON

---

Also consider using [data service](http://Lightning%20Data%20Service) for such simple actions like [Create Records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_salesforce_write).

For building up forms, there is [record-edit-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form), [record-view-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-view-form) and [record-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form) base components available.

Comment: +1 Even `{'sObject' : 'Account'};` is not needed.